# XNA object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xna

I have created a bouncing ball game and I have setup collisions so that my ball bounces of objects. I would like it so after the ball has bounces off the object the object is deleted. After looking up how to do this I am trying to set my Box (object) class to null (which should delete the object) after it is hit.

For some reason however after the ball hits it and tries to set the box to `null` I get the following error on the draw method inside Game1.cs:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Code setting the Box to `null`:

```
if (hastouched == 3)
{
    Box = null;
}
```

I am receiving the error in the main draw function in Game1.cs on this piece of code:

```
Box.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Is this something anyone knows straight up why it could be happening or would you like to see more of my code? If so, what parts?
Thanks

Comment: You are setting Box to null, and then trying to draw it.

Comment: To avoid this you could add a check if(Box != null){Box.Draw(spriteBatch)};

Comment: You could also add a property on your `Box` class, that stores the status of your object: `IsInactive`. When your `Box` object is in use, the value would be set to `true`. You would then set it to `false` instead of `null`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Brandon - work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are saying, you are setting to null an object and trying to draw it, that's why you receive that error.

I think that the better way to do this is to make your `Box` class to inherit from `DrawableGameComponent`, so when you create a new instance of it you only have to add it to `Game.Components`, in this way XNA will handle its `Update` and `Draw` methods on its own.
When you want to remove it you can simply call `Game.Components.Remove(Box)` (of course Box here is meant as a variable, not the class).

Comment: thank you for your help once again, I decided to go for the    'if(Box != null){Box.Draw(spriteBatch);}'   method as it was quicker however I will definitely take that into account for next time :)

Comment: This is a suitable solution if you have several objects to manager, but if you have only that box *Brandon*'s solution is the best one :)